# SVG Editor with nice ui and text editor

Tags: graphics, software

Do you know a nice svg editor for MAC OS?

My needs are:

- Nice svg produced
- Splited view with text editor

Comment: Adobe Illustrator?

Answer (score 1):

Inkscape works great on Mac OS:
http://www.inkscape.org/

I have used is for years to produce icons and logos in SVG and then export to PNG for the web.

I've never had the need but the features list does list "Live watching and editing the document tree in the XML editor".  I believe that's what you meant by "text editor".  I hope that Inkscape works well for you.